# How to include header files for Python extension in c (CPython)

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to write a python extension that enables me to use my already working c library in python (working on Raspbian and compiling with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc) .
The setup.py compiles (with some warnings) but when I import the extension (bme) in my python3 interpreter i get the following error

```
>>> import bme
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bme.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: bsec_sensor_control
```

The bsec_sensor_control function is defined in the bsec_interface.h header.
I tried to include the header directly into the program via relative path.
Here is my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

bme_module = Extension('bme',
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include',
                    '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/algo/normal_version/bin/RaspberryPi/PiThree_ArmV6',
                    '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/config/generic_33v_3s_28d',
                    '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example'],
    library_dirs = ['../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/algo/normal_version/bin/RaspberryPi/PiThree_ArmV6'],
    libraries = ['pthread', 'm', 'rt', 'wiringPi'],
    # extra_objects = ['../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/algo/normal_version/bin/RaspberryPi/PiThree_ArmV6/libalgobsec.a'],
    extra_compile_args = ['-fPIC'],
    depends = ['bsec_integration.h', 'bsec_interface.h', 'bsec_datatypes.h', 'bsec_integration.c', 'bme680.c', 'libalgobsec.a'],
    sources =['Pybme.c', '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example/bsec_integration.c', '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example/bme680.c'])

setup (name = 'bme',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'Provide BME68X and BSEC outputs for python',
    author = 'Nathan',
    # url='https://url/of/website',
    ext_modules = [bme_module],
    headers = ['../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example/bme680.h',
                '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example/bme680_defs.h',
                '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example/bsec_integration.h',
                '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example/bsec_interface.h',
                '../BSEC_1.4.8.0_Generic_Release/examples/bsec_iot_example/bsec_datatypes.h'])
```

Since I already tried a lot of things now I would be very happy about some advise on how to fix this or how to figure out the problem.

Thanks
Nathan

Comment: Functions are not **defined** in header files. They're **declared in header files**, and the definition is in the `.c` file. Are you sure that too is included in the sources...

Comment: You either need to link an .o or a library (BSEC Sensor Library?) that defines the symbol in question.

Comment: so the symbol bsec_sensor_control is declared in bsec_interface.h and implemented in the libalgobsec.a. I tried to link the files accordingly but as the error suggests i did it wrong. So how do i need to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the object, archive or library that defines the symbol `bsec_sensor_control`.  Bosch requires you to accept a license to [download](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/software-tools/software/bsec/) the library so that is how I am willing to push it.  They do provide build information on github for [BSEC-Arduino-library](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BSEC-Arduino-library).

Comment: If i understood things right, the function is defined in the bsec_interface.h and implemented in the libalgobsec.a.  So how do link those files in the setup.py?